# Dompdf laravel mail attachment having issue in server

Tags: laravel, email, dompdf

I have created an auto invoice generate option in my laravel app using dompdf, its working fine in my local pc, but in my server its having below error in my log file and job queue also failed. I am adding pdf generate option in job queue file, its looks so fine in my localhost

```
[2020-03-17 11:09:00] production.ERROR: Class 'Dompdf\Cpdf' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Dompdf\\Cpdf' not found at /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Adapter/CPDF.php:198)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/CanvasFactory.php(57): Dompdf\\Adapter\\CPDF->__construct('a4', 'portrait', Object(Dompdf\\Dompdf))
#1 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php(300): Dompdf\\CanvasFactory::get_instance(Object(Dompdf\\Dompdf), 'a4', 'portrait')
#2 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/ServiceProvider.php(50): Dompdf\\Dompdf->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(799): Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\ServiceProvider->Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('dompdf', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(776): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('dompdf', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1245): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('dompdf')
#8 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/ServiceProvider.php(58): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->offsetGet('dompdf')
#9 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(799): Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\ServiceProvider->Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#10 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('dompdf.wrapper', Array)
#12 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(776): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('dompdf.wrapper', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/Facade.php(20): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('dompdf.wrapper')
#14 /var/www/html/panaroma-services/app/Jobs/OrderCompleteJob.php(43): Barryvdh\\DomPDF\\Facade::__callStatic('loadView', Array)
#15 [internal function]: App\\Jobs\\OrderCompleteJob->handle()

    public function handle()
    {
        $getOrderDtls = $this->pdf;
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('order.pdf.invoice', compact('getOrderDtls'));
        $order_no = str_pad($this->data['order_id'], 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $path = public_path('pdf/invoice_pdf/');
//        $path = url('pdf/invoice_pdf/');
        $fileName =  $order_no . '.' . 'pdf' ;
        $pdf->save($path . '/' . $fileName);
        $pdf->download($path . '/' . $fileName);
        $pdf_file_path = $path . $fileName;
        \Mail::send($this->template_name, $this->data, function($message) use($pdf_file_path) {
            $message->to($this->email)->subject($this->subject)->attach($pdf_file_path);
        });
    }
```

here is my import

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use PDF;
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: According to this line in your exception `production.ERROR: Class 'Dompdf\Cpdf' not found`, seems like the import part of the `Dompdf\Cpdf` is not right. Can you paste your controller code where you use this class?

Comment: i have added it here, i am doing this in my job queue file

Comment: What does your import at the top look like?

Comment: i have edited with my import

Comment: Try to change your PDF import to this: `use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;`

Comment: still same error :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209786/discussion-between-asif-uddin-and-zlatan).